# СonEmu цепляется за верхнюю часть экрана

Tags: conemu

После того, как переустановил этот шелл, он начал цепляться за верхнюю часть экрана и я не могу его свободно перемещать по всей площади монитора. Порылся в настройках нашел только этот параметр отвечающий за перемещение по оси абсцисс, но для свободного перемещения по оси ординат так и ничего не нашел. Вопрос в том, как разблокировать свободное перемещение окон по всей площади экрана ?

[image: Вот так цепляется]
[image: Настройки в general size and pos]

Comment: Как выглядят настройки в разделе General -> Size & Pos?

Comment: Я прикрепил пикчей в самом вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cпасибо @[Дмитрию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/417748/%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9) за ответ нашел данный параметр в настройках ConEmu

[image: Вид окна:]

Answer (score 1):

Сам мучился - надо отключить quake режим

Comment: А поподробнее? Где его искать и прочее?)

Comment: @DaemonHK см. https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsQuake.html самая верхняя галка